# AdMob test banner loads on simulator, Only real banner loads on device?

Tags: ios, singleton, admob

I can't get a test banner to load on a device. However, test banner loads on simulator no problem. I'm trying to test my AdMob/iAd singleton mediation. It works fine with test ads on simulator but AdMob never loads the test banner on actual device.

The following is the code to present AdMob banner:

```
    self.adBanner_=[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)]; 

    adBanner_.hidden=NO;

    adBanner_.delegate = self;   

    adBanner_.adUnitID = @"Unit-ID";

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    [self.adBanner_ loadRequest:request];

    self.adBanner_.rootViewController = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner_];   

    isLoaded_ = YES;   

    //  request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ]; <--loads test ad on simulator

    request.testDevices = @[ @"number" ];  <--supposed to load test ads on real device
```

Why aren't I receiving AdMob test ads on real device yet there's no problem with AdMob test ads on simulator? Is code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just run your app on your test device. In the Debug Area AdMob will give you your test ID like so:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"testDeviceIDNumber" ]
```

After that just place your testDeviceIDNumber here:

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[ @"testDeviceNumberIDNumber"];
[self.adBanner_ loadRequest:request];
```

For keep testing on the simulator also, add @"Simulator" in this row:

```
request.testDevices = @[ @"testDeviceNumberIDNumber", @"Simulator"];
```

Comment: I'm using AdMobSDKiOS 7.0.0. I followed the iOS quick start guide on AdMob site and i'm not getting any log message when the device loads.

Comment: @Jet - All you have to do to see this is to switch ON your bottom area (debug area) in Xcode. The same area where NSlog displays texts... In the Debug Area AdMob will give you your test device ID. No need to mention copy/paste after that :)  

Do not forget to plug your test device and to select this real device as target device for running...